# Indicate selected tile(s) on tilemap

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Anyone have any suggestions on how I can indicate selected tile(s) in a Tiled tilemap without resorting to creating a 'selection tile'?  I merely need to brighten the tile selected.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Update:  I ended up simply altering the opacity of the selected tile itself.  Provides an unexpected possibility - fog of war.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used a tilemap before.  Have you tried setting the image colour?  I have not done this before myself but I am fairly certain it creates a sort of tint effect.

If that does not work you could simply use CCLayerColor (setting to the same size as the square) with limited opacity to place over the selected tile.  Assuming you are using square tiles that aren't rotated, this should be quite easy.

Another option is as you said to create a selection tile.  But you can create one that is used for all as it doesn't have to replace the tile.  You can just put a sprite on top of your tile and limit opacity so that all it does is change it's colour or brightness (it being the tile below).

Comment: Actually, I'm using irregular shaped hex tiles; although not rotating.

Comment: Then you would be best to create an overlay tile that would colour the tile below it, or try setting the sprite.color property.